# How to derive Sommerfeld radiation conditions from Limiting Absorption Principle?

Tags: waves, scattering

For the Helmholtz equation
$$
-(\Delta + k ^2) u = f, \tag{1}
$$
imposing the Sommerfeld radiation condition
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty} r ^{\frac{m-1}2} \left( u_r - i k u\right) = 0
$$
on $u$ allows us to pick a unique solution for $(1)$. I have seen this condition derived by looking at the asymptotics in $r$ of the resolvent $R(k) = -(\Delta + k^2)^{-1}$ as $k$ tends to the real line, and I want to know if this is an approach that can be generalized to other operators. The Wikipedia page on the Sommerfeld radiation condition mentions there is a connection to the Limiting Absorption Principle.

I could not find any references, but for the Laplacian operator $P(k) = - \Delta - k ^2$ defined on $H^2(\Bbb R^m) \Subset L^2(\Bbb R^m)$, my best guess is as follows.

We know
$$
||u||_{L^{2, -\sigma}} \lesssim ||P(k)u||_{L^{2, \sigma}} \tag{2}
$$
for $\sigma > 1/2$, where $L^{2, \sigma}$ is given by integration against the measure $(1 +|x|^2)^{\sigma} \text d x$. From this, given any $f \in L^{2, \sigma}$, we have that $u_n = R(\lambda + i n^{-1}) f$ is bounded in $L^{2, -\sigma}$ for $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ and $n =1, \dots$, so the Banach-Alaoglu theorem furnishes a weak* limit $u \in L^{2, -\sigma}$ s.t. for all Schwartz-type test functions $\varphi$ we have
$$
\langle u_n, \varphi\rangle \to \langle u, \varphi\rangle. 
$$
This implies that $u$ is a distributional solution to $P(\lambda) u = f$, so elliptic regularity results show $u \in H^{2, \text{loc}}$ and $e^{-r/n}u$ is in the domain of $P$. If $k = \lambda + i n ^{-1}$, we have $P(k) = P(\lambda) - 2i n ^{-1} \lambda  + n ^{-2} $, so
\begin{align}
P(k) e ^{- r/n} u &= -(u \Delta e ^{- r/n} + 2 \nabla e ^{- r/n} \cdot \nabla u + e ^{-
                           r/n} \Delta u + k ^2 e ^{- r/n} u)
  \\
  &= -u \left(  n ^{-2} e^{-r /n}-\frac{n ^{-1}  e^{-r/n}}{r} \right) + 2 n ^{-1}  e ^{- r/n} u_r + e ^{-
     r/n} P(k) u
  \\
  &= \frac{e ^{-r/n}}{n r} u + 2 n ^{-1}  e ^{- r/n} (u_r - i \lambda u) + e ^{-
     r/n} f  ,
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align*}
||P(k)  e ^{-r/n}u-  e ^{-r/n}f||_{L ^{2, \sigma}} &\lesssim n ^{-1}|| r ^{-1} e ^{-r/n} u||_{L ^{2, \sigma}}
                                                     + n ^{-1} ||e
                                                   ^{-r/n}(u_r - i \lambda u)||_{L ^{2, \sigma}} .
\end{align*}
Combining this with $(2)$, picking $\sigma$ slightly above $1/2$, and letting $n \to \infty$ yields:
\begin{align*}
||u||_{L ^{2, -\sigma}} \lesssim ||f||_{L ^{2, \sigma}} + \lim_{n\to \infty} n ^{-1} ||e ^{-r/n}(u_r - i
  \lambda u)||_{L ^{2, \sigma}}. 
\end{align*}
This last term looks a lot like the Sommerfeld radiation condition. In fact, if the weak* limit that produced $u$ preserved this condition, the limit $u$ would be unique and the resolvent could be at least weakly extended to $\lambda$.

My question is whether this calculation is correct, and if it is, how much of it generalizes to other (possibly non-self adjoint) operators $P(k)$. Obviously the functions $e^{-r/n}$, as well as the pair of dual spaces $L^{2, \pm \sigma}$ would have to be replaced, but is there a general framework around this procedure?

Comment: I think you can expect get better answers here https://mathoverflow.net/questions?tab=Newest